# Spring Cloud Data Flow Stream Dynamic Topics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have followed the tutorial in
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-kafka/

to develop 3 apps. 1 source (Usage-Detail-Sender), 1 processor(Usage-Cost-Processor) and 1 sink(Usage-Cost-Logger). The Java codes are as followed in that tutorial.

I start up the Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) server with this guide https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker-customize/.

I registered all the apps in the SCDF server. Then I created a stream and deployed it. The code works as fine. The topics shown in my kafka zookeeper when I typed

```
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

in the zookeeper docker container shows

```
usage-stream.usage-processor
usage-stream.usage-sender
```

In my application.properties for the 3 apps are as followed,

**usage-detail-sender**

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=usage-detail
# Kafka Binder Properties #
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka-0,kafka-1
```

**usage-cost-processor**

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=usage-detail
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=usage-cost

# Kafka Binder Properties #
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka-0,kafka-1
```

**usage-cost-logger**

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=usage-cost
# Kafka Binder Properties #
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka-0,kafka-1
```

***Question 1***:
Why does the topics show `usage-stream.usage-processor` & `usage-stream.usage-sender` instead of usage-detail and usage-cost? I suspect it is something to do with launching the 3 apps as a stream in SCDF?

***Question 2***:
How can I send dynamic topics to Kafka? Base on the tutorial code, they seem to use `org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source` to send the message to kafka. However, this only works with single topic.

I tried to use `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BinderAwareChannelResolver` as suggested in other threads to send dynamic topic. 
eg

```
private BinderAwareChannelResolver resolver;
Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(this.data)
                .build();
        boolean isSent = this.resolver.resolveDestination(this.topic)
                .send(message);
```

However, my processors and sink applications are not able to listen and detect these topics when i launch the apps with SCDF as a stream.

How do i solve this? Thank you